# get all .vcf file in a single folder

Tags: android

i am making .vcf file off all contacts stored in contacts list and save it in sdcard as well but all .vcf file are storing sepratly in my SDCARD , iwant to make a folder in side Sdcard and save all the .vcf file inside it...and finally get the path of folder and able to mail it in email id..so how to make a folder to save all .vcf file inside it if there are thousands of contacts in contact list of my device.

my code for making .vcf and save it in sdcard are below. pls modified on the same or provide some new idea...

```
 private void getVcardString() {
             int j=0;
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                vCard = new ArrayList<String>();
                cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
                if(cursor!=null&&cursor.getCount()>0)
                {
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    for(int i =0;i<cursor.getCount();i++)
                    {
                        get(cursor);
                        Log.d("TAG", "Contact "+(i+1)+"VcF String is"+vCard.get(i));
                        publishProgress(Integer.toString(j));        
                        j++;
                        cursor.moveToNext();
                    }
                    csv_status = true;
                   }
                else
                {
                    Log.d("TAG", "No Contacts in Your Phone");
                }

         }
       public void get(Cursor cursor)
            {
                vfile = "Contacts" + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis()+".vcf";

                //String vfile = "Contacts"+".vcf";
                //cursor.moveToFirst();
                String lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
                AssetFileDescriptor fd;
                try {
                    fd = CsvSender.this.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
                    FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
                    byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
                    fis.read(buf);
                    String vcardstring= new String(buf);
                    vCard.add(vcardstring);
                    String storage_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + vfile;
                    FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(storage_path, false);
                    mFileOutputStream.write(vcardstring.toString().getBytes());
                }catch (Exception e1) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: please specify the problem you are facing when doing this? Are you getting any error or exception?

Comment: there is not any error on above code but now i want to make a folder and save all .vcf contacts inside it..so i dont know how to do this..thats why i post question in SOF..pls help me ..